# Find the global temp table names from the sql script

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure, where multiple times some global tables are created (start with `##`). I want to list out the table Names. For example -

```
create table ##customer
(
    Customerid bigint
)

if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Department')) is null
begin
    create table ##Department
    (
       Departmentid bigint
    )
end

SELECT * FROM ##customer
```

I want to list out the Temp Table names, which are created and which are used as a select query. Please help. 1st priority using SQL query. If you do not have idea in sql, then using C#. I will pass the Stored procedure content to C# method.

Answer (score 1):

To list global temp tables you can run the following command:

SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '##%'